# Squid3 SSL-BUMP

Tags: ssl, squid

I am having a squid 3.3 running in my Ubuntu server. In my squid ssl-bump configuration i am getting the following error as the result of squid3 -k reconfigure.

Error:

FATAL: Bungled squid.conf line 1137: http_port 3127 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/xxx/xxx/xx/xxx.pem key=/xxx/xxx/xx/xxx.pem
Squid Cache (Version 3.1.19): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.008 seconds = 0.004 user + 0.004 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 17344 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0

I have nothing in cache.log or in access.log.

Currently i can successfully log full URL for HTTP in access.log. But My goal is to log FULL URL of ssl installed websites in my access.log.

Comment: The output says squid version 3.1.19, while you say 3.3. And while the ssl-bump options you use are documented for 3.3, they are not documented for 3.1 so I guess they are not available there.

Comment: Thanks your reply. can you post me any reference sites that you might know that will helpful for me to configure this ssl-bump in squid version3.1.19

Comment: http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.1/cfgman/http_port.html

Comment: Hi Steffen Thanks a lot for your effort. Is there any another post that will help me to configure squid with ssl-bump from the scrap.

Comment: No, but I'm sure google will help you - it looks like there are several pages, some about configuration and some about help with configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use the https_port tag not http_port for SSL traffic.

Comment: Can confirm this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: `FATAL: Unknown https_port option 'ssl-bump'.` and `FATAL: Unknown http_port option 'ssl-bump'.` (`Squid Cache: Version 4.10`)